# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSON object doesn't have the primary key field 'id'

Tags: java, json, parsing, realm

I use realm to parse this JSON, but I get this error:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JSON object doesn't have the primary key field 'id'.**

[LINK of Json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/48fc430501465a207d1e25d446d1aabc/raw/dc086e911eecb9e4f9770d87c8fad5b9fd610651/b548aca4-6358-11e7-ae4c-fbb837ffe2c8.json)

this is my method :

```
    Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        r.beginTransaction();
        r.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Application.class,result);
        r.commitTransaction();
```

my Application class is :

```
public class Application extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private RealmList<girl> girls;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public RealmList<girl> getGirls() {
        return girls;
    }

    public void setGirls(RealmList<girl> girls) {
        this.girls = girls;
    }

    public Application() {
    }

    public Application(int id, RealmList<girl> girls) {
        this.id = id;
        this.girls = girls;
    }
}
```

my class girl is

```
public class girl extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String ville;
    private String tel;
    private String photo;
         //getters and setters and constructors with and without params
}
```

Comment: The JSON data and model defination look correct. Are you sure the `result` you passed in is the same with the JSON data you posted? Also, the `result` should be the JSON data with all application's fields as the root elements, like `{"id": 1, "girls": [xxx]}`.

Comment: Any solution you found so far ?

Comment: had the same issue, removing the object name solved the issue. in this case "  "application": { ..."

Answer (score -2):

try to use `realm.copyFromRealm();` and for more refer bellow link

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1973